# error : invalid label when i try to get json from url SENCHA TOUCH

Tags: sencha-touch

I try with the following code and i get error: invalid label

```
Ext.util.JSONP.request({
            url: 'http://demo.webfactory.mk/',
            callbackKey: 'callback',
            params: {
                action: 'retrieve',

            },
            callback: function(data) {
                console.log('Inside data');
                var dataarray = data.result;
                console.log(dataarray);

            }

    });
```

Comment: I pasted that code in my browser and it worked for me. Can you explain to me why you are are initiating a JSONP request this way instead of using a Model with a ScriptTagProxy?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Ajax request instead of JSONP, below is the code sample. This works for me.

> **Note** that you cannot make cross domain Ajax calls, in chrome so u cant test in chrome. You need to deploy your Sencha script to the same Web
>   server you are accessing. But All mobile browser supports this cross
>   domain Ajax calls.

Go ahead and implement the same.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: reqUrl,
        defaultHeaders : 'application/json',
        success : function(response, opt) {
            dataarray = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
            //App.views.viewport.reveal('nextScreen');
        },
        failure : function(response, opt) {
            Ext.Msg.alert('Failed', response.responseText);
        }
    });
```